# Sort() function not working in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, typeerror

I have the following expression that aims to `filter` an array in the following sequential order:

- filters the array using `.includes` `searchTerm`
- sorts the results with those that start with the `searchTerm` appearing first by using `startsWith`
- then sorts the results by having the shortest words appearing at the top, using `.sort`.

Expression:

```
let wordsFiltered = wordList
                    .filter(x =>shoetest.simplify(x).toLowerCase()
                            .includes(shoetest.simplify(searchTerm).toLowerCase()))
                    .sort((a, b) => b.startsWith(searchTerm) - a.startsWith(searchTerm))
                    .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
```

2 errors:

- `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)`
- `The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2363)`

I tried solutions I found online using `valueOf()`, `toString()`, and `as string` but they don't seem to work.

Comment: The error "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type" occurs when you have an arithmetic operation with values that are not of type any, number or enum, e.g. a Date. To solve the error convert the values to numbers.

Comment: startsWith return `true` are you sure you want to type cast with subtracting .

Comment: @MohitSharma thanks. What is your suggestion on how I best achieve this?

Comment: just read `sort` behaviour from `mdn` and you get answer by own.

Comment: You could just add `+` in front of it `+a.startsWith()`

Comment: Also, you are chaining two `sort`. That will only use the final sort logic, so `startsWith` logic is completely ignored

Comment: I don't know why this is closed. They have added the code along with the screenshot of the error (The code was in a single line. So wasn't visible) @gnat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sort` function needs to return either a negative number to put `a` before `b`, a positive number to put `b` before `a`, or zero to leave as-is. `.startsWith` returns a boolean, so you're effectively doing something like `true - false`, which typescript doesn't like.

As such, it's easier to rewrite your last two sorts as this:

```js
  .sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.startsWith(search) && !b.startsWith(search)) {
      return -1;
    } else if (!a.startsWith(search) && b.startsWith(search)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      // Either both or neither start with search term, so sort by length.
      return a.length - b.length;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the boolean to numbers by appending `+` and then subtract them.

```
.sort((a, b) => +b.startsWith(searchTerm) - +a.startsWith(searchTerm) )
```

---

There's another issue. You are chaining 2 `sort` calls. This will only use the second `sort` call while ignoring the first one. If you are trying to do a `thenBy` sort where if both the items `startsWith` the same `searchTerm` then use the shortest one first, you need to include that in the same `sort` using `||`

```
// Declare it outside. No need to compute this in every call. 
let shoetestValue = shoetest.simplify(searchTerm).toLowerCase();

let wordsFiltered = wordList
  .filter(x => shoetest.simplify(x).toLowerCase().includes(shoetestValue))
  .sort((a, b) => 
        +b.startsWith(searchTerm) - +a.startsWith(searchTerm) 
          || a.length - b.length
      )
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const searchTerm = "b";
const wordList = ["yellow", "black", "blue", "red"];

const wordsFiltered = wordList
  .sort((a, b) =>
    +b.startsWith(searchTerm) - +a.startsWith(searchTerm) 
    || a.length - b.length
  )

console.log(wordsFiltered)
```

[**Typescript Payground with sample data**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQNwhgTsDOCmkGMAWAVWEC2wC8wBEARngNwBQokwA7gPYQAmAMgJbQAuOwA2oQDZgIA1ngA0%20ArwCusUfgCesXrxpVZeCLHp4AumVK9YHWg2gAxZrzbpNnY01ZtywAHTQ6bABQewYggEocAD5gJ2Aw8IBqAlc2SDZoAHVmNiQPOERUdAwAgFpgCLAYuMTk1PSIZDRMANDwuoAfeuBCgwA7AHMU4Dzots6kWrC-UlIEGla3A2dldo87MwsrDXo-IA)